# adding spec flow table data into hashtable

Tags: c#, specflow

```
| FieldName | header | code    | 
| a1        | test   |         |
| a1        | test   | 1       |
| a1        | test   | 2       | 
| a1        | test   | 3       | 
| a1        | test   | 4       | 
| a1        | test   | 5       | 
| b2        | prod   | 1       | 
| b2        | prod   | 2       | 
| b2        | prod   | 3       |
```

I have the following code to loop thru the table and add the data in a hashtable.
Currently my code only adds one a1 and b2. but what I am planing to do is add them       all in my hashtable with a different key.
For example: ("a11",value), ("a12",value); ("a13",value); and the same for b2..ect.

```
 public Hashtable GetData(Table table, string headerType)
    {

        var data = table.CreateSet<SpecFlowData>();
        var hashtable = new Hashtable();
        hashtable.Clear();

        foreach (var currentRow in data)
        {
            var key = currentRow.FieldName;
            var value = new Hashtable();

            GetValue(value, currentRow);

            if (hashtable.ContainsKey(key)) //continue;
            {
                var r = new Random();
                key = key + r.Next();
            }
            var format = (string)value["header"];
            if (headerType == format)
            {
                hashtable.Add(key, value);

            }
            break;
        }


        return hashtable;

     }
```

Update: Here is the getvalue method:

```
     private static void GetValue(Hashtable value, SpecFlowData currentRow)
      {
        value.Clear();

        value.Add("code", currentRow.Code);
         value.Add("name", currentRow.FieldName);
        value.Add("header", currentRow.HeaderType);
       }
```

Why is my data not added properly. thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry to mean "not added properly".

Comment: what does `GetValue(Value,currentRow)` do?  why are you making a new random every time?  (and why using random at all?  why not use an int and do `key = key + i++`?)

Comment: John..I did that to create a random number to use as a key for the hashtable. I also added the getvalue method on my post.

Comment: why are you trying to stuff all this into a hashtable with random key names?  so far, this looks like misusing a hashtable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking out of the `foreach` loop at the end of your first iteration, so there can only be one key-value-pair in your Hashtable.

If you remove the `break` statement, you will get more values. As @JohnGardner mentioned, you should not use a random, because it *may* produce identical values. Simply use an increasing integer variable.

So after all, this should do:

```
public Hashtable GetData(Table table, string headerType)
{
  var data = table.CreateSet<SpecFlowData>();
  var hashtable = new Hashtable(); // no need to clear a newly created Hashtable
  int i = 1;

  foreach (var currentRow in data)
  {
    var key = currentRow.FieldName;
    var value = GetValue(currentRow);

    if (hashtable.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        key = key + i++;
    }
    var format = (string)value["header"];
    if (headerType == format)
    {
      hashtable.Add(key, value);
    }
  }
  return hashtable;
}

private static Hashtable GetValue(SpecFlowData currentRow)
{
  var value = new Hashtable();

  value.Add("code", currentRow.Code);
  value.Add("name", currentRow.FieldName);
  value.Add("header", currentRow.HeaderType);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation ... that was the issue.